# Why doesn't my WCF call return JSON?

Tags: c#, wcf, json

I've followed online examples from here and Google with no success: meaning I have experimented with various configurations to no avail.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

THANKS!

**UPDATE:**
I really just want to capture JSON from the web-service.  So, if I don't HAVE to configure the WCF service as a REST-ful service, then that is okay with me.

**THE HTML SIDE LOOKS LIKE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        var pageController =
        (function ($) {
            var publicInstances = {};

            publicInstances.controller = controller;
            function controller() {

                var self = this;

                self.form = null;
                self.wcfService = 'http://localhost:2798/Service.svc';

                self.Type = null;           // GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                self.Url = null;            // Location of the service
                self.Data = null;           // Data sent to server
                self.ContentType = null;    // Content type sent to server
                self.DataType = null;       // Expected data format from server
                self.ProcessData = null;    // True or False

                this.initialize = function () {
                    self.form = new form(self);
                };

                this.invoke = function (onSuccess) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: self.Type,
                        url: self.Url,
                        data: self.Data,
                        contentType: self.ContentType,
                        dataType: self.DataType,
                        processData: self.ProcessData,
                        complete: self.onComplete,
                        error: self.onError,
                        success: onSuccess
                    });
                };
                this.onComplete = function (xmlHttpRequest, status) {
                    alert("onComplete");
                };
                this.onError = function (xmlHttpRequest, status, error) {
                    alert("onError");
                };

                this.listPeople = function () {
                    self.Type = 'POST';
                    self.Url = self.wcfService + '/ListPeople';
                    self.Data = null;
                    self.ContentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
                    self.DataType = 'json';
                    self.ProcessData = true;

                    self.invoke(self.dataBindListPeople);
                };
                this.dataBindListPeople = function (data, status, xmlHttpRequest) {
                    // This runs but no repsonse exists???
                    alert("dataBindListPeople");
                };

                self.initialize();
            };

            publicInstances.form = form;
            function form(controller) {

                var self = this;

                self.controller = controller;

                self.btnListPeople = $('#btnListPeople');

                this.initialize = function () {
                    self.btnListPeople.click(self.listPeople);
                };

                this.validate = function () { return true; };
                this.disable = function () { };
                this.enable = function () { };

                this.listPeople = function () {
                    if (self.validate());
                    self.controller.listPeople();
                };

                this.populateListPeople = function (json) {
                    alert("populateListPeople");
                };

                self.initialize();
            };

            return publicInstances;
        })(jQuery);

        var defaultPage = null;

        $j(document).ready(function () {
            defaultPage = new pageController.controller();
            var stop = "";
        });
    -->
    </script>

<input type="button" id="btnListPeople" value="List People" />
```

**THE web.config LOOKS LIKE:**
This was automatically created when I added the SERVICE REFERENCE into the project.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" 
                 closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                 openTimeout="00:01:00" 
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 allowCookies="false" 
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferSize="65536" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                 messageEncoding="Text" 
                 textEncoding="utf-8" 
                 transferMode="Buffered"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                        maxStringContentLength="8192" 
                        maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                        maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:2798/Service.svc" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" 
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**THE WCF SERVICE SIDE LOOKS LIKE:**

```
namespace WcfService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<Person> ListPeople();
    }
}

namespace WcfService
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
        public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
        {
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;
            this.Age = age;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace WcfService
{
    [ServiceBehavior]
    public class Service : IService
    {
        public List<Person> ListPeople()
        {
            List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
            people.Add(new Person("Peyton", "Manning", 35));
            people.Add(new Person ("Drew", "Brees", 31));
            people.Add(new Person("Brett", "Favre", 58));

            return people;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing two incompatible worlds here...

1) in your config you define `basicHttpBinding` - this is a **SOAP** binding, and SOAP is not well suited to be called from jQuery or Javascript. It typically also returns **XML** (not JSON)

2) in your service contract however, you seem to be referring to REST-based WCF:

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

but in order for this to work, you need to use the REST-based binding - `webHttpBinding` (and possibly the suitable `WebServiceHostFactory` and/or possibly the `<webHttp />` endpoint behavior.

You should go to the [WCF REST Developer Center on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/WCF/REST) to learn how to properly set up a REST WCF Service that will return JSON to your callers!

Comment: I just want it to return JSON.  Do I still need to setup as RESTFUL service?

Comment: @PrisonerZERO: yes, I would - JSON fits best into a WCF **REST** service.

Comment: Do you know of a simple online example...the link you gave has WAY too much reading.

Comment: @PrisonerZERO: there are [also tons of screen cast (no reading required)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/rest+starter+kit+endpoint+screencasts) - [start with this one](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Screencast-Getting-Started-with-the-WCF-REST-Starter-Kit)